# How can I scale an object but have the texture repeat

Tags: texturing, shaders, scale

I'm working on a project where I will be having a lot of trim along walls. I will need to create a trim object potentially over a hundred times and all trims will have different lengths. I am hoping that I can keep one master trim object around and make copies of it as needed then stretch the object as needed without having the texture stretch with the object. I would have imagined that this is some basic functionality and would require a simple checkbox for texture repeating or something. Unfortunately, I've searched around and can't get any ones solution to work for me.

This is the current master object I have (the black part with the bottom. The orange is not apart of it)
[image: Master object]

This is the end goal of the object. I should be able to stretch it as far as I need while the texture just repeats
[image: end goal]

This is my current shader. Now I'm a total newb at blender so I could be doing something very wrong here but I have a texture, a specular map on the blue layer, and a normal map.
[image: My current shader]

This appears to be the commonly suggested solution though it appears as though many people do it slightly different. I've tried several variations of it but it all seems to result in something similar to the image below this one yet still doesn't get the texture to repeat instead of stretch.
[image: suggested solution]

The only change the above solution gives is some weird vertical graininess. If I connect the mapping to all 3 image textures it looks like the whole image is just vertical lines
[image: result of the suggested solution. Weird vertical graininess]

Edit:
Thanks to the comment by Susu I think I've got the way to get this working for my case. It took a little extra googling to figure out what everything in the linked answer meant but below is my current solution. I linked the Texture Coordinate to the mapping through the object. Changed all image texture nodes from Flat to Box. Altered the scale until my texture looked correct.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208668/uniformly-repeated-image-on-objects-with-different-dimensions/208671#208671